# css3, opacity, bg-image, opacity

Tags: css3

Есть блок

`.design c bg-image`, `position=relative>`

в нем обертка

`div.wrapper_bg_opacity`

которому дал белый

`bg-color=white & opacity=0.75 position: absolute`

на выходе прозрачность есть но: картинки блоке ,`wrapper` отображаются без прозрачности но текст имеет прозрачность, хотя `wrapper_bg_opacity и wrapper` на одном уровне стоят.

Пробовал с `z-index--ом` играться, но что-то не то делаю,
мне просто нужно чтоб `bg-картинка` имела чуть прозрачность, а все что внутри было видно четко

```
<section class="design">
  <div class="wrapper_bg_opacity"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>For all devices</h1>
    <p class="h2">Unique design</p>
    <hr class="border_line_red">
      <div class="img_bgi">
        <img class="img1" src="img/White1.png" alt="#">
        <img class="img0" src="img/White.png" alt="#">
      </div>
  </div>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.design {
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px;
  position: relative;
}

.design .wrapper_bg_opacity {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/rN1sNQf.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .55;
  z-index: 1;
}

.design .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="design">
  <div class="wrapper_bg_opacity"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>For all devices</h1>
    <p class="h2">Unique design</p>
    <hr class="border_line_red">
      <div class="img_bgi">
        <img class="img1" src="img/White1.png" alt="#">
        <img class="img0" src="img/White.png" alt="#">
      </div>
  </div>
<section>
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Comment: @Skyline73731, не за что. Если не трудно, отметьте его галочкой как правильный)